# Flutter FallThroughError

Tags: flutter

```
/C:/Users/melvi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_web-2.8.10/lib/src/utils/web_utils.dart:71:13: Error: Method not found: 'FallThroughError'.
      throw FallThroughError();
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/melvi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_web-4.6.1/lib/src/utils/web_utils.dart:263:9: Error: Method not found: 'FallThroughError'.
  throw FallThroughError();
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/melvi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.7.7/lib/src/platform_interface/utils/load_bundle_task_state.dart:13:13: Error: Method not found: 'FallThroughError'.
      throw FallThroughError();

dependencies:
  firebase_core_platform_interface: ^4.5.1
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
  clipboard: ^0.1.3
  cloud_firestore: ^3.5.1
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
  dio: ^5.3.2
  dotted_border: ^2.0.0+3
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.19
  firebase_core: ^1.24.0
  firebase_messaging: ^13.0.4
  firebase_storage: ^10.3.4
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_braintree: null
  flutter_datetime_picker:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/HasanAlqaisi/flutter_datetime_picker.git
  flutter_easyloading: ^3.0.5
  flutter_google_places: ^0.3.0
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a specific error related to the FallThroughError in some Dart files of your dependencies. This error may be due to a change in Dart SDK or the use of a newer version of a package you are using that expects a method not present in your current Dart SDK.

You can try updating your packages to their latest versions using the `flutter pub upgrade` command.

Check the compatibilities of the versions of your Dart SDK and your dependencies.